# Web Scrapping just return None

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a pop-up program with mir4 draco price. But the price return `None` :

```
import requests                                                                                      
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                        
                                                                                                 
urll = 'https://www.xdraco.com/coin/price/'                                                          
                                                                                                 
headers = {                                                                                          
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
              "Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}                                              
                                                                                                 
site = requests.get(urll, headers=headers)                                                           
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html5lib')                                                          
                                                                                                 
price = soup.find('span', class_="amount")                                                           
                                                                                                 
print(price)
```

Comment: Dynamic content, populated by JS. Can't parse it like this, you need to use the library that has a JS engine, like Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to parse a site that is dynamically loaded using JS as @jabbson mentioned.

This might be a way to get the data you want.

If you check the network requests being made by the page, you will find that it makes calls to a few different APIs. I found one that might have the info you're looking for. You can make POST requests to this API as shown below...

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*','user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

html = requests.post('https://api.mir4global.com/wallet/prices/hydra/daily', headers=headers)
output = json.loads(html.text)

# 'output' is a dictionary. If we index the last element, we can get the latest data entry
print(output['Data'][-1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'CreatedDT': '2022-08-04 21:55:00', 'HydraPrice': '2.1301000000000001', 'HydraAmount': '13434', 'HydraPricePrev': '2.3336000000000001', 'HydraAmountPrev': '5972', 'HydraUSDWemixRate': '2.9401340627166839', 'HydraUSDKLAYRate': '0.29840511595654395', 'USDHydraRate': '6.2627795669928084'}
```